# Adding INTERVAL to TIME in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

In PostgreSQL (Using pgAdmin 3... That is what my school demands us to use) I'm having an error message when I try and check in a trigger if the NEW event is at the same time as another event going on. 'stime' is in data type TIME and stands for "start time" and 'duration' is in data type INTERVAL.

```
if (NEW.stime >= schedule.stime AND NEW.stime <= (schedule.stime + schedule.duration))
--Checking if the new event happens while another event is.
```

The given error is as follows:

```
    ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "schedule"
LINE 5:   (NEW.stime >= schedule.stime AND NEW.stime <= (schedule.st...
                        ^
QUERY:  SELECT (NEW.sdate IN (SELECT sdate FROM schedule)) AND
        --Checking for events in the room at given date.
        (NEW.rno IN (SELECT rno FROM schedule WHERE NEW.sdate = schedule.sdate AND NEW.bno = schedule.bno)) AND
        --Checking if the new event happens while another event is.
        (NEW.stime >= schedule.stime AND NEW.stime <= (schedule.stime + schedule.duration))
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function trigf1() line 12 at IF
********** Error **********

ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "schedule"
SQL state: 42P01
Context: PL/pgSQL function trigf1() line 12 at IF
```

I'm also posting here the required CREATE for room and schedule and the trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE room (

rno INT     NOT NULL,

bno INT     NOT NULL,

function VARCHAR (30),

capacity INT,

PRIMARY KEY (rno, bno)

);

CREATE TABLE schedule (

sdate DATE  NOT NULL,

stime TIME  NOT NULL,

rno INT     NOT NULL,

bno INT     NOT NULL,

eid INT     NOT NULL,

duration INTERVAL,

FOREIGN KEY (rno, bno) REFERENCES room (rno, bno)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigf1() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$

DECLARE

BEGIN
    IF 
    --Checking if the new event is in revent or sevent
    (NEW.eid IN (SELECT reid FROM revent) OR (NEW.eid IN (SELECT seid FROM sevent))) AND
    --Checking if the room exsists
    (NEW.rno IN (SELECT rno FROM room)) AND 
    (NEW.bno IN (SELECT bno FROM room WHERE NEW.rno = room.rno) ) THEN
        IF
        --Checking for other events on the same day.
        (NEW.sdate IN (SELECT sdate FROM schedule)) AND
        --Checking for events in the room at given date.
        (NEW.rno IN (SELECT rno FROM schedule WHERE NEW.sdate = schedule.sdate AND NEW.bno = schedule.bno)) AND
        --Checking if the new event happens while another event is.
        (NEW.stime >= schedule.stime AND NEW.stime <= (schedule.stime + schedule.duration)) THEN
        BEGIN
            RAISE NOTICE 'ERROR: Could not add given row to schedule';
            RETURN NULL;
        END;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER T1 BEFORE INSERT ON schedule

FOR EACH ROW

EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigf1();
```

Comment: That leaves a lot open. Knowing the error message might help to help you for starters.

Comment: Right! I'll edit the post to include the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access rows from `schedule` without a query. Try to change

```
(NEW.stime >= schedule.stime AND NEW.stime <= (schedule.stime + schedule.duration))
```

to:

```
EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM schedule
               WHERE new.stime >= schedule.stime
                     AND new.stime <= (schedule.stime + schedule.duration))
```

But your construct seems to check for every wanted condition and only if everything is OK, it throws an error. Maybe you need to negate everything.

Comment: Alright I'll post the more extensive code in a  few minutes

Comment: @TalMushkin: That's more or less how I imagined it. So my solution should fit in general. But maybe your `IF`s are doing the opposite of what you want? See my edit.